# LINQ error: System.NotSupportedException on GroupBy Selection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When `var items = q3.ToList();` executes from the code snippet below, it throws exception System.NotSupportedException. The aim is to get the list of `items` after the grouping.

Exception: 
`Unable to create a constant value of type 'AppDB.Stage.Rules'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

```
  var valuations = context.stage
                .Where(q => q.stageID == stageID && !rules.ToList().Any(r => r.type1 == q.type1 || r.type2 == q.type2))
               .GroupBy(q => q.stageKey)
               .Select(g => g) ;

            var q3 = valuations.Select(y => new StageType
            {
                TypeKey = y.Key,
                TypeName= "UNKNOWN",
            });
            var items = q3.ToList(); //error here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database doesn't have any idea of what your in-memory `rules` actually is, and in-turn cant convert this statement to SQL

The simplest solution will be to leave it as an `IQueryable` and don't use `ToList`,

```
context.stage
       .Where(q => q.stageID == stageID && !rules.Any(r => r.type1 == q.type1 || r.type2 == q.type2))
       .GroupBy(q => q.stageKey)
       .Select(g => g) ;
```

**However**, if it is already in memory, then you will have to send the values as a primitive list

```
var type1s = rules.Select(x => x.type1);
var type2s = rules.Select(x => x.type2);

context.stage
       .Where(q => q.stageID == stageID && !type1s.Contains(q.type1) && !type2s.Contains(q.type2))
       .GroupBy(q => q.stageKey)
       .Select(g => g) ;
```

Comment: is there a way to turn rules which is type `List` to use in sql? Is it correct I either have to Stage.ToList() or rules.Select(..)?
The Stage table is huge, I can't to go through rule by rule.

Comment: @grepLines yes there are ways i guess, however the will require expressions that will just do the same thing. In short if rules are an in memory construct, then you will need to use `Contains` which will convert to SQL equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Because `rules.ToList()` makes results in memory, you can't use it inside an `IQueryable` that executes over SQL. You should first bring your data into memory and then narrow it by other in-memory object.

```
 var valuations = context.stage.ToList()
                .Where(q => q.stageID == stageID && !rules.ToList().Any(r => r.type1 == q.type1 || r.type2 == q.type2))
               .GroupBy(q => q.stageKey)
               .Select(g => g) ;

            var q3 = valuations.Select(y => new StageType
            {
                TypeKey = y.Key,
                TypeName= "UNKNOWN",
            });
            var items = q3.ToList();
```